# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hist'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with following variables.

```
 df.iloc[:, [8, 10,12,14,16]]
    m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
    0   1.465425    0.369512    0.195093    0.090899    0.075437
    1   1.090584    0.630911    0.289951    0.169461    0.065148
    2   8.393636    1.147147    0.406641    0.388952    0.284973
    3   1.089455    0.265552    0.124755    0.074697    0.066011
    4   0.809997    0.465886    0.187011    0.114472    0.049296
    5   6.213920    0.820291    0.241337    0.178089    0.169355
    6   0.854443    0.327344    0.180940    0.081440    0.066603
    7   0.640819    0.581226    0.181652    0.162496    0.072640
    8   4.916334    1.024343    0.556189    0.310475    0.301980
    9   1.481441    0.318333    0.190325    0.101531    0.070593
    10  1.103429    0.569323    0.196212    0.174342    0.097093
```

I am trying to have sumperimposed histogram via this code:

```
plotname=["m1", "m2","m3","m4","m5"]
count=0
for var in df.iloc[:, [8,10,12,14,16]]:
    print(var, count)
    var.hist(var, label=plotname[count])
    count=count+1
```

It fails with following error-message:

```
m1 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-5a27316eb0a9> in <module>()
      3 for var in df.iloc[:, [8,10,12,14,16]]:
      4     print(var, count)
----> 5     var.hist(var, label=plotname[count])
      6     count=count+1

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hist'
```

How could one make the for loop on the columns of pandas dataframe and plot it via similar code style?

Thank you,

Comment: its fixed, I mnaged to have the proper plot the way I want :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do in this way :

```
plotname=["m1","m2","m3","m4","m5"]
for index, var in enumerate(df.iloc[:, [8,10,12,14,16]]):
     print(var, index)
     df[var].hist(df[var], label=plotname[index])
plt.show()
```